# Access one methods input parameters in another method of same class

Tags: apex, webservices, method

In my web service method i am passing few string parameters. I want to use these parameters in error message body. I simply can't put these strings as it will give error :

> Variable does not exist

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CreatrixSync/*')
global class CreatrixSync{

@HttpPost
global static String doPost(String userId,String password, String firstName, String lastName, String application_email, String application_mobile, String admissionStage, String admissionStatus, 
    String application_name, String application_cycle, String application_program, String applicationId, String application_city, 
    String application_state, String application_country, String application_pincode, String application_workexp, String applicationUrl, String spjat_testRegId, 
    String spjat_name, String spjat_createdDate, String spjat_marks, String spjat_email, String spjat_mobile) {

    try{
        //Query for leads matching with given email or mobile
        External_System_Mapping__c[] LeadProgram = [Select Salesforce_Value__c from External_System_Mapping__c Where Mapping_Type__c = 'Program' and External_System_Value__c =:application_program ];
        List<Lead> matchingLeadsListWIProgram;
        if (leadProgram != null && leadProgram.size() > 0) {
            matchingLeadsListWIProgram = [Select Id, Status from Lead where isConverted = false and ((Program__c =: LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c) and ( (Email != null AND Email = :application_email) OR (MobilePhone != null AND MobilePhone = :application_mobile) OR (Email != null AND Email=:spjat_email) OR (MobilePhone != null AND MobilePhone =:spjat_mobile))) ];
        }else{
            matchingLeadsListWIProgram = null;
        }
        List<Lead> matchingLeadsListWOProgram = [Select Id, Status from Lead where isConverted = false and ((Email != null AND Email = :application_email) OR (MobilePhone != null AND MobilePhone = :application_mobile) OR (Email != null AND Email=:spjat_email) OR (MobilePhone != null AND MobilePhone =:spjat_mobile)) ];

        if(matchingLeadsListWIProgram != null && matchingLeadsListWIProgram.size() > 0){ 
            for(Lead lead : matchingLeadsListWIProgram ){

                //if(firstName != null){lead.FirstName            = firstName;}
                //if(LastName != null){lead.LastName             = lastName;}
                if(admissionStage != null){lead.Admission_Stage__c   = admissionStage;}
                if(admissionStatus != null){lead.Admission_Status__c  = admissionStatus;}
                if(application_name != null){lead.Application_Name__c  = application_name;}
                if(application_cycle != null){lead.Application_Cycle__c = application_cycle;}
                if(applicationId != null){lead.Application_Id__c    = applicationId;}
                //if(application_city != null){lead.Lead_City__c  = application_city;}
                if(application_state != null){lead.Lead_State_From_Creatrix__c = application_state;}
                if(application_country != null){lead.Lead_Country_From_Creatrix__c      = application_country;}
                if(applicationUrl != null){lead.Application_Url__c   = applicationUrl;}
                if(spjat_testRegId != null){lead.Spjat_Test_RegId__c  = spjat_testRegId;}
                if(spjat_name != null){lead.Spjat_Name__c        = spjat_name;}
                if(spjat_createdDate != null){lead.Spjat_CreatedDate__c = spjat_createdDate;}
                if(spjat_marks != null){lead.Spjat_Marks__c       = spjat_marks;}                       
                if(application_workexp != null){lead.Application_Work_Experience__c   = application_workexp;}
                lead.Application_Received__c = 'Yes';

                if(application_pincode != null && application_pincode.length()> 0){
                    application_pincode  = application_pincode.deleteWhitespace();
                    lead.Pincode_From_Creatrix__c = application_pincode;
                }

                if(applicationId == null){lead.Application_Status__c = 'Partial Application';} else{lead.Application_Status__c = 'Applied';}
                lead.Initial_Sales_Lead_Status__c = lead.status;
                lead.Program_From_Creatrix__c = application_program; 
                lead.Partial_Application_Enabler__c = true;                 

                /*if(LeadProgram.size() > 0){                                  
                    lead.Program__c           = LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c;
                } */


         }

            update matchingLeadsListWIProgram;
        }else{

             //Query for Accounts matching with given email or mobile
            Id personAccId = [Select Id From RecordType  Where SobjectType = 'Account' and name = 'Person Account'].Id;
            List<Account> matchingAccountsList;
            if (leadProgram != null && leadProgram.size() > 0) {
                matchingAccountsList = [Select Id, Type from Account where RecordTypeId =:personAccId And ((Program__c =: LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c) and ((PersonEmail != null AND PersonEmail =:application_email) OR (PersonMobilePhone != null AND PersonMobilePhone =:application_mobile) OR (PersonEmail != null AND PersonEmail =:spjat_email) OR (PersonMobilePhone != null AND PersonMobilePhone =:spjat_mobile)))];
            }else{
                matchingAccountsList = null;
            }
            if(matchingAccountsList != null && matchingAccountsList.size() > 0){
                for(Account account : matchingAccountsList ){

                    //if(firstName != null){account.FirstName            = firstName;}
                    //if(lastName  != null){account.LastName             = lastName;}
                    if(admissionStage != null){account.Admission_Stage__c   = admissionStage;}
                    if(admissionStatus != null){account.Admission_Status__c  = admissionStatus;}
                    if(application_name != null){account.Application_Name__c  = application_name;}
                    if(application_cycle != null){account.Application_Cycle__c = application_cycle;}
                    if(applicationId != null){account.Application_Id__c    = applicationId;}
                    //if(application_city != null){account.City__c              = application_city;}
                    if(application_state != null){account.Lead_State_From_Creatrix__c = application_state;}
                    if(application_country != null){account.Lead_Country_From_Creatrix__c = application_country;}                   
                    if(applicationUrl != null){account.Application_Url__c   = applicationUrl;}
                    if(spjat_testRegId != null){account.Spjat_Test_RegId__c  = spjat_testRegId;}
                    if(spjat_name != null){account.Spjat_Name__c        = spjat_name;}
                    if(spjat_createdDate != null){account.Spjat_CreatedDate__c = spjat_createdDate;}
                    if(spjat_marks != null){account.Spjat_Marks__c       = spjat_marks;}                                  
                    if(application_workexp != null){account.Application_Work_Experience__c   = application_workexp;}

                    if(application_pincode != null && application_pincode.length()> 0){
                        application_pincode  = application_pincode.deleteWhitespace();
                        account.Pincode_From_Creatrix__c = application_pincode;
                    } 

                    account.Program_From_Creatrix__c = application_program;
                    /*if(LeadProgram.size() > 0){                                  
                      account.Program__c         = LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c;
                    }*/

                }

                update matchingAccountsList;

                }else{

                //if Lead and Account both do not exist, then create lead with status as Not Contacted
                Lead lead = new Lead();

                if(application_email != null){
                lead.Email = application_email;
                } else if(spjat_email != null){
                lead.Email = spjat_email;
                }
                if(application_mobile != null){
                lead.MobilePhone = application_mobile;
                } else if(spjat_mobile != null){
                lead.MobilePhone = spjat_mobile;
                }

                lead.FirstName            = firstName;
                lead.LastName             = lastName;
                lead.Application_Name__c  = application_name;
                lead.Admission_Stage__c   = admissionStage;
                lead.Admission_Status__c  = admissionStatus;
                lead.Application_Cycle__c = application_cycle;
                lead.Application_Id__c    = applicationId;
                //lead.Lead_City__c    = application_city;
                lead.Lead_State_From_Creatrix__c = application_state;
                lead.Lead_Country_From_Creatrix__c     = application_country;
                if(application_pincode != null && application_pincode.length()> 0){
                    application_pincode  = application_pincode.deleteWhitespace(); 
                    lead.Pincode_From_Creatrix__c = application_pincode;
                }

                lead.Application_Url__c   = applicationUrl;
                lead.Spjat_Test_RegId__c  = spjat_testRegId;
                lead.Spjat_Name__c        = spjat_name;
                lead.Spjat_CreatedDate__c = spjat_createdDate;
                lead.Spjat_Marks__c       = spjat_marks;                                  
                if(LeadProgram.size() > 0){                                 
                  lead.Program__c         = LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c;
                }
                if(LeadProgram.size() > 0){
                  if(LeadProgram[0].Salesforce_Value__c == 'No Program'){
                    lead.LeadSource = 'Web Direct';
                  }else{
                    lead.LeadSource = 'Direct';
                  }
                }
                lead.Program_From_Creatrix__c = application_program;
                lead.Application_Work_Experience__c   = application_workexp;      
                lead.Application_Received__c = 'Yes';
                lead.Status = 'Not Contacted';
                lead.Original_Source__c = 'Offline Sources';
                lead.Application_Received__c = 'Yes';
                if(applicationId == null){lead.Application_Status__c = 'Partial Application';} else{lead.Application_Status__c = 'Applied';}
                lead.Initial_Sales_Lead_Status__c = '';

                if(matchingLeadsListWOProgram != null && matchingLeadsListWOProgram.size() > 0){
                  for(Lead lead2 : matchingLeadsListWOProgram){

                          lead2.Duplicate_Lead_program__c = application_program;

                      update lead2;
                  }
                }


                insert lead;
                return generateResultJSON('success', 'Lead Created Successfully');

               }

        }


        return generateResultJSON('success', 'Record updated Successfully');
    }catch(Exception e){
        sendErrroMail(e.getMessage());
        return generateResultJSON('error', e.getMessage());                   

    }
}

 public static String generateResultJSON(String result, String message){
        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField('result', result);
        gen.writeObjectField('message', message);
        gen.writeEndObject();
        return gen.getAsString();
}
 public static void sendErrroMail(String errorMessage){            
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
         String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'[redacted]@gmail.com', '[redacted]@gmail.com', '[redacted]@[redacted].org'};
         mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);  
         mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Data modification error');
         mail.setSubject('Data modification Failed @: ' + UserInfo.getOrganizationName());
         mail.setPlainTextBody(errorMessage + '\n' + 'JSON Request:' + 'firstName' + firstName);

         Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}



}
```

Here i want to use input strings arguments(eg. `firstName`) from `doPost` method in `sendErrroMail` method eg.use `firstName` in mail body.

Comment: Is that possible to cut source code to show only lines with definitions and place of error? Nobody will really check where at 13 places with firstName mentions error can happens

Comment: Hi Kurunve, I want to use parameters being passed to "doPost" method into method "sendErrroMail".  I am getting error on this line :          mail.setPlainTextBody(errorMessage + '\n' + 'JSON Request:' + 'firstName' + firstName);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different way to go about it. You *could* make `static` variables to hang on to this information:

```
static String requestFirstName;

@HttpPost
global static String doPost(...)
{
    requestFirstName = firstName;
}
```

However, this information is application state, so using `static` isn't really appropriate. More proper would be to pass these variables through as additional method parameters. Note that I renamed your horribly misspelled method to `sendErrorEmail`.

```
@HttpPost
global static String doPost(...)
{
    // other logic
    sendErrorEmail(errorMessage, firstName);
}
public static void sendErrorEmail(String errorMessage, String firstName)
{
    // now firstName is defined
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply change your signature to:

```
public static void sendErrroMail(String errorMessage, String firstName){
```

and then call it like this:

```
sendErrroMail(e.getMessage(),firstName);
```